# I'm scraping links that have similar dictionaries. How do I differentiate between each dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm scraping links from a used goods website that gives me similar dictionaries. Motor related links have one type of dictionary with extra dictionary keys, one of which I need.
The other links contain all other used goods and have a slightly smaller dictionary.
I'm not sure what to do at this stage.
I've tried to assign the motor related dictionary a name with 'motordict = {x:alldata[x] for x in keys1}' but this causes conflicts for some reason and maybe I'm going about things the wrong way.
I'm stumped at the moment and would appreciate any help.

dictionary 1. Motor related goods

dict_keys(['header', 'description', 'currency', 'price', 'county', 'breadcrumbs', 'displayAttributes', 'views'])

dictionary 2. All other used goods

dict_keys(['header', 'description', 'currency', 'price', 'county', 'breadcrumbs', 'views'])

```
 alldata = json.loads(x)
        
        keys2 = ['header', 'breadcrumbs', 'views']

        keys1 = ['header', 'county', 'displayAttributes', 'countyTown', 'breadcrumbs', 'views']

        motordict = {x:alldata[x] for x in keys1}

        views = motordict.get('views')
        title = motordict.get('header')
        county = motordict.get('county')
        countyTown = motordict.get('countyTown')
        itemId = motordict.get('id')
        sellerId = motordict.get('seller')['id']
        sellerName = motordict.get('seller')['name']
        adCount = motordict.get('seller')['adCount']
        lifetimeAds = motordict.get('seller')['adCountStats']['lifetimeAdView']['value']
        currency = motordict.get('currency')
        price = motordict.get('price')
        adUrl = motordict.get('friendlyUrl')
        adAge = motordict.get('age')
        spotlight = motordict.get('spotlight')
```

Comment: what does "causes conflicts" mean? it's not clear what your goal is. `x` is undefined in your example, so you should hard-code into the example and reduces the number of keys for clarity.